# Which ORM is best suited for reporting module?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, ibatis

We are using `IBatis` in one module and `Hibernate` in another module.
In general, which of the two ORM is best suited for reporting?
I personally feel `IBatis` is best suitable for reporting.
Please tell your thought on this....

Comment: That's nice. I think Views work good for reporting.

Comment: Thanks pst.  
Views are at database level while the IBatis and Hibernate are at application level. I am little confused on the answer. Please help me out to understand your thought. Have Great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per me : iBatis is better choice because of:

1. In reporting you may need to write complex queries. Writing complex queries in iBatis is very easy.
2. You only require to read data, need not to worry about database updates. In case for heavy use of database write operations i recommend Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks Satish. I too think so and I go with your thought. KUDOS!......